# get last updated time for cell in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is likely a simple problem, but I am new to using google apps scripts. I am trying to write a function that tells me the last time a specific cell within a different sheet than the active one was updated.

The codes I have tried are:

```
function lastEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var lastUpdated = s.LastUpdated();
   s.getRange('A2').return(lastUpdated);
}
```

and

```
function lastEdit(input) {
 r = Date(input)
 return(r)
}
```

The first one kicks up an error that .LastUpdated() is not a function and the second only gives me the current Date/Time. Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1) post the code you currently have even if it's wrong. 2) accessing a cell of a different sheet that is not active is a question that has been asked here more than hundred of times.

Comment: You might be able to get this information from Drive Activity API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no Apps Script method for spreadsheets called `LastUpdated()`

As a workaround, you can

- implement an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger
- Save on each edit of the specified cell the modification date in [scriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties?hl=en)
- Retrieving the date of the last update by querying for the value saved in the script properties

Sample:

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
const updatedCellNotation = "A1"
const props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function lastEdit(){
  var lastUpdated = props.getProperty("lastDate")
   s.getRange('A2').setValue(JSON.parse(lastUpdated))
}

function onEdit(e){
var editedCell = e.range.getA1Notation()
 if(editedCell == updatedCellNotation && e.range.getSheet().getName() == s.getName()){
 props.setProperty("lastDate", JSON.stringify(new Date()))
 }
}
```

- Note that for writing values into a cell you need to use the [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) method - `return` is not a valid method for it
- Please refer to the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) for other valid Apps Script methods.

Comment: Thanks ziganotschka. I am trying to get the last updated info from an existing sheet. Unfortunately, the sheet was produced by a colleague, without implementing such an onEdit function prior to entering data. Can I retrieve this info without previously setting the properties of a cell, or is this impossible?

Comment: If you are talking about events in the past, then you can only retrieve this information through [version history](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308971?hl=en). In principle possible programmatically, but if you need it only once for already past events - probably easier to go through the version history manually,

Comment: Thank you. This combined with your previous answer are exactly what I was trying to figure out. I'll be able to figure it out from this. Cheers.